# Google Charts "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid column index 3. Should be an integer in the range [0-3]."

Tags: google-visualization

Before you mark this as duplicate, note that others are asking about the error `Invalid column index undefined. ...` or `Invalid column index 5. Should be an integer in the range [0-4].`  But no.  Mine is "3 should be an integer in the range of [0-3]."  Also, the table does work without the `formatter.format()` line (just no formatting).

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':[data.chartType.toLowerCase()]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    var googleData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    for (var h in data.headers) {
        googleData.addColumn(data.headers[h].type, data.headers[h].html);
        if (data.headers[h].format) {
            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(data.headers[h].format);
            console.log(data.headers[h].format);
            formatter.format(googleData, h); // Errors Here
        }
    }
    /* ... Add Rows ... Draw Chart ... */
}
```

The header in question looks like this:

```
header[3] = {
    "html": "Total Amount",
    "source": "total_amount",
    "type": "number",
    "format": {
        "negativeColor": "#F05840", //orange
        "negativeParens": true,
        "pattern": "#,###",
        "prefix": "$",
        "suffix": "",
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why it would be erroring.

Please forgive me for any typos here, I had to hand-edit the spacing and remove my company's specific info upon pasting the code here.

---

#### Edit

WhiteHat is correct in that my `h` variable was a string instead of an integer, and calling `parseInt` did remove that error.  However, instead of calling `parseInt` on the formatter and wherever else it's needed, I got rid of my `for (var h in data.headers)` calls and went with the bog-standard `for (var h = 0; h < data.headers.length; h++)`. Although more verbose with more room for typos, it's far more standardized and predictable.

I'm still having issues with GoogleCharts NumberFormatter, but that's for another round of research and questions, not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you're passing a number (`3`),
and not a string (`'3'`),
by using --> `parseInt`...

e.g.

```
formatter.format(googleData, parseInt(h));  // <-- here
```